# Angular dart tutorial with angular 1.0. Cannot resolve a circular dependency

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have problems to get the angular dart tutorial working with 1.0. I managed it with chapter 1 to 4. In chapter 5 and 5 I get the error message:

> Cannot resolve a circular dependency! (resolving DirectiveMap -> DirectiveSelectorFactory -> ElementBinderFactory -> ComponentFactory -> ShadowDomComponentFactory -> ViewFactoryCache -> Http -> RootScope -> Object -> Http)

See https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial

Answer (score 1):

During a migration from 0.14.0 to 1.0.0 I had this particular impossible circular dependency with Scope injection. You're not supposed to inject Scope anymore, but to implement ScopeAware interface when you need the Scope.

Answer (score 0):

They just released AngularDart 1.0 the other day and I don't think they've gotten around to updating the tutorial yet. In the mean time, if you just want an example web app to look over, you could check out [viktor savkin's repo](https://github.com/vsavkin/angulardart-sample-app). I think it's been updated to work with 0.14 which was the last beta release.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a pull request for an update to Angular.dart 1.0 https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/pull/131